# I want to match two Urls in Python using regular expressions, but following code gives an error. I cannot figure out why

Tags: regex, python-2.7

```
input = 'susaya https://sousfs@sls.sus.uk/de/sekd/sho/project1/first_project'

url_match = re.match("\s*susaya\s+([^ ]+)", input)
```

When I try to print url_match, I get the memory location.

```
print url_match
None
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x5f630cs48e40>
```

1. What is the output of regular expression `("\s*susaya\s+([^ ]+)`?
2. I get `None` when I try to print because url_match doesn't match?

I am using python2.7. Thanks.

Comment: The first line is not valid Python. Do you mean `input = 'susaya https://sousfs@sls.sus.uk/de/sekd/sho/project1/first_project'`?

Comment: And that's not an error, that's a match object.

Comment: Yes!  I have edited. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`re.match` doesn't return a string, it returns a match object.  Calling `group(i)` on the match object returns the i'th capture group, with the 0th capture group being the entire match.

```
>>> input = "susaya https://sousfs@sls.sus.uk/de/sekd/sho/project1/first_project"

>>> url_match = re.match(r"\s*susaya\s+([^ ]+)", input)
>>> url_match.group(0)
 'susaya https://sousfs@sls.sus.uk/de/sekd/sho/project1/first_project'
```

The pattern `"\s*susaya\s+([^ ]+)"` matches zero or more spaces, followed by "susaya", followed by one or more spaces, followed by a capture group of one or more characters that are not spaces.

Comment: Upvoted, though best practice would be to also use a `r"raw string"` for the regex.

Comment: That's true - I just copied the question's code.  Fixed. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Could someone please help me on my question number 1? it will help massively to debug the problem. Thanks.

Comment: Added an explanation of the the regex pattern.